# Gitweb Apache Output Different Than Terminal

Tags: perl, apache2, cgi-bin, gitweb

Apache is configured like so:

```
Alias /git /var/www/gitweb
Alias /gitweb /var/www/gitweb

<Directory "/var/www/gitweb">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI +Indexes
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

  DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

  SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG /var/www/gitweb/gitweb.conf
</Directory>
```

I am trying to setup Gitweb, but I keep getting the dreaded `404 - No projects found` issue. Usually this is a permissions error so I wanted to see if anything was printed by perl not having permissions so I ran it from the terminal with this command

```
sudo -u apache GITWEB_CONFIG=/var/www/gitweb/gitweb.conf perl gitweb.cgi
```

The script echoed the HTML with all of the repositories properly listed (i.e., no 404).

Here is the question: **why would the same script run from Apache and the terminal behave differently?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was SELinux. My repositories are in the directory `/home/git`. The httpd service was not able to access that directory by default.

Ran `setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs=1` and the issue was resolved.